# Cloudinary Images Not Working via Ionic Framework

Tags: ios, angularjs, ionic-framework, cloudinary

I'm using Cloudinary images with the Ionic framework via the [`cloudinary-angular`](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular) library and I'm having some issues with the images loading.

When I test via the `ionic serve` method, things seem to work fine. However, when I install the app to the device, the images break. Anyone have any ideas of how to fix this?

The following are examples of some of my code:

```
<cl-image ng-if="item.Attachment.name" public-id="{{bucket.mybucket}}/{{item.Attachment.name}}" crop="thumb" width="100" height="100" radius="max" format="png"></cl-image>
<cl-image ng-if="!item.Attachment.name" public-id="{{bucket.mybucket}}/{{bucket.defaultCheese}}" crop="thumb" width="100" height="100" radius="max" format="png"></cl-image>
```

and:

```
$scope.backgroundImg = $.cloudinary.url($scope.bucket.mybucket + "/" + results.response[0].Attachment.name, { format: 'png', height: 800, width: 580, crop: 'fit' }).toString();
```

And like I said, both of these work using `ionic serve`.

**Update:** Using Safari debug tool, I discovered the following.
[image: SafariDebug]

**Fixed One Issue:** App Transport Security issue was fixed by adding the following to the app's Info.plist under `Resources/MyApp-Info.plist`. More details at [App Transport Security](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/technotes/App-Transport-Security-Technote/index.html).
[image: AppTransport]

**Fixed Second Issue:** Ended up being an issue with the [cloudinary_angular](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_angular) library. For some reason, it's returning the url with the `file://` prototocol instead of the `http://` one that the app needed. See the solution via my fork [robksawyer/cloudinary_angular](https://github.com/robksawyer/cloudinary_angular/commit/9e68a57c2965f9f301d0918c2e4674ce8cd68c25).

Answer (score 0):

probably a whitelist error?

see complete info here https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

Quick Info

```
// install plugin
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist
```

Then modify your config.xml appropriately

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src *; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; script-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline' 'unsafe-eval'">
```

See documentation provided above for complete explaination

Comment: I initially thought that was the issue as well, but then I reviewed my config.xml and I had the content policy set. However, to double check, I ran `cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist` and it gave me the following:

Comment: https://gist.github.com/robksawyer/6a83dad2bf9db156e845

Which makes me think it never installed it for ios.

Comment: Ended up getting it installed via `ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.1.0`, but still no luck. I was sure to run `ionic prepare ios` and `ionic build ios` as well before testing. Thanks though, it was worth a shot.